# Django formset non_form_errors as i have more than 1000 forms in a formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I have a formset which is a modelformset_factory.And when the formset validates it throws a non_form_error like "Please submit 1000 or fewer forms.".I have more than 2000 forms in the same formset. is it possible to validate the formset ?. And how to overcome the above issue?

Please guide,
Thanks

Comment: check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#limiting-the-maximum-number-of-forms

Comment: can you provide you code for formset_factory ?

Comment: Thanks. I got the solution.Just increased max_num.